# Data Model persistence between requests

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building an application using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy.

In the application I use database models written in the SQLAlchemy declarative language, let's say that I have a table called *Server*.
The application, by design choices, ask the user -via WTForms- to set values for the fields of the Server table between **different pages(views)** and I need save the instance to the database in the **last view**.

---

My problem is: I have 2 'circular' views and  would like to store the instances of objects created in the *first view* directly in **the database session**  in order to be able to query the session in the *second view*  and committing the result only in the last view (the end of the loop), like the pseudocode shows (very simplified, it makes no sense in this form but is to explain the concept):

```
def first_view():
form = FormOne() #prompt the first form
if form.validate_on_submit():
    #form validate, i create the instance in SQLalchemy
    server = Server() #Database Model
    server.hostname = form.hostname.data
    loop_count = form.repetition.data
    session['loop'] = loop_count 
    db.session.add(server) #adding the object to the session
    #but i'm not committing the session in fact the next view needs to know about this new object and a third view needs to commit based on the user input
    return redirect(url_for('second_view'))
return render_template("first_view.html", form=form)

def second_view():
form = FormTwo() #prompt the second form
if form.validate_on_submit():
    hostname_to_search = form.hostname.data #i get some other input
    #i use the input to query the session (here different server instace can appear, depends on the user input of the first view)
    rslt= db.session.query(Server).filter(Server.hostname==hostname_to_search ).all()
    #the session is empty and doesn't contain the instance created in the previous view... <-- :(

    if session['loop'] <= 0 :
       #end the loop
       return redirect(url_for('commit_view'))
    else:
      loop_count = session.pop('loop',1)
      session['loop'] = loop_count-1
      #go back to the first page to add another server instance
      return redirect(url_for('first_view')) 
return render_template("first_view.html", form=form)


def commit_view():
    #loop finished, now i can commit my final instances
    db.session.commit() <--here i save the data, db.session is empty 
return 'DONE!'
```

but SEEMS that the session in Flask-SQLAlchemy is **local to the request**, so it appears that between a view and another the db.session **is resetted/empty**.

The first solution came into my mind is to store even the server object values in the `flask.session` (in json format) but this means that I need to jsonify and parse back every time the flask.session to build back the objects in each view: I cannot use the query power of the database, but for example I have to manually check if the hostname input by the user is already present in the previously created server objects.

---

My question is: how is possible(if it is possible and good practice) to keep the db session 'open' between different views:

- How can i implement this?
- Is it convenient?
- Is it thread safe?

Maybe i'm using the wrong approach to solve the problem? (Of course I can do a single page, but the real case in much more complex and needs to be structured between different pages)